# How do I create a vector of bitmasks that basically replaces a vector of boolean in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a vector of bitmasks to store true/ false values which are going to tell me if the value particular index in another vector needs to be printed or not.

eg: `std::vector<int> a ;`
b is a vector of bitmasks which is going to hold flag values that correspond to the integer vector a and this flag tells me if that particular value at the corresponding index needs to be printed or not.

```
a {1,2,3}  
b { true, false ,true} // I need a similar bitmask which would help me print 1 and 3
```

this task can be achieved in other ways the problem I am working in requires the use of bitmask. Thanks in advance for helping me with this.

Comment: It seems like you have a use-case for `vector<bool>`. Why not use it? Might be worth resolving that issue instead of trying to invent a new wheel.

Comment: @user4581301 well the issue is I could but having a vector of bitmasks works better with other parts of the code apparently still trying to figure out how. But yeah I wanted to know how can we initialize them and make them perform the same functions as of a bool. Would having an master enum work ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"vector of bitmasks"*, either a `std::vector<bool>` or a (dynamic) bitmask ([`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) has static size)...

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "bitmask"? As I understand the term, a bitmask has more than one bit, each capable of masking something. So you seem to be asking for a vector of *bits* that will serve *as* a bitmask.

Comment: Yeah vector of bits would work because they’re simply replacing the bool(basically they should have 0s and 1s) Also, I want to know how do you initialize it and access it’s contents. I am planning to store both the integer array and this bit mask array in a structure and perform other tasks using them. I could use a map or any other data structure but due constraints from other parts of the code I am trying to use this. Also, I want to be able to perform or and and functions quite often.

Comment: @mandelbrot You're OK with a vector of bits, so we're back to why not use [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for [efficient use of boolean true and false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126881/efficient-use-of-boolean-true-and-false-in-c)? What specifically are the requirements imposed by the "other parts of the code" you mentioned?

Comment: `std::vector<std::optional<int>>` might also be a viable alternative depending on how much you need to optimize the space. But if you really need to optimize space, then do you need the whole 32 bits (or 64 bits) of an integer?

Answer (score 0):

As many suggested already, I would have done this like this:

- `myBitset` will keep the flags. `1`(set) for print flag and `0`(clear) for non-print flag

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  std::vector<int> a {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  std::bitset<10> myBitset;

  myBitset.set(3);             // set fourth bit  ==> display 4
  myBitset.set(6);             // set seventh bit ==> display 7
  myBitset[8] = true;          // set nineth bit ==> display 9
  myBitset[9] = myBitset[3];   // set 10th bit ==> display 10

  std::cout << "Mybitset" << myBitset << endl;

  for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
  {
      if (myBitset.test(i))
      {
          std::cout << a.at(i);
      }
  }

  return (0);
}
```

The ouput would be:

```sh
1101001000
47910
```